# jQuery identifying a form where page has multiple forms

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been following a tutorial on using jQuery modal with forms. I keep seeing statements like:

```
var form = $('form')[3];
```

Why does the code have `[3]`, or whatever number?

Comment: Accessing a jQuery object by index retrieves the Element object at that index of the collection. In your example, it would return you back the 4th `<form>` Element in the DOM. Note that there may be a better way to do this, though. Exactly which is right for you depends on the use case.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan that explain it perfectly. Now I understand. Thank you Rory.